# Lowe's won't accept their store credit - any recourse?

Tags: mistakes, shopping, gift-card

At one point in the past I returned some items to Lowe's (big hardware & home goods box store in the US) without a receipt. So they gave me a card in place of cash which I can redeem there - and scanned my driver's license at the same time. It was around $50 on the card.

Recently I went to use this card but when they again scanned my license as verification, apparently it didn't match the card and so they would not accept it.

My license has not changed, so I assume this is some type of technical error or maybe a mistake made when the card was issued. When I gently pressed the checkout person about this she said there was nothing she could do.

I don't know if this is a common problem, but in all other instances at any store this has never happened before.

Any recommendations on how to encourage them to accept the card despite the error?

Comment: Did you ask them what the problem is?

Comment: They said that my license didn't match the card... which makes no sense. That's why it seems like an error.

Comment: Maybe it's a transcription (typo) or transposition (numbers flipped) error.  That's the first line of "attack" that I'd use.  (Not that I'd actually verbally attack them.  Firmness with good manners is the honey that catches this fly.)

Comment: Also, the checkout person is not who you want to deal with: go straight to customer service, where a manager can get involved if necessary. For only $50, I'm surprised this wasn't just a standard, anonymous gift card in the first place.

Comment: How long ago was "_one point in the past_"? I believe store gift cards sometimes come with expiration dates, so it may have expired. It's at least possible that system or human error may have mangled this into "_does not match_". Again, customer service would be the place to ask.

Comment: @TripeHound it was within the last few months, but I will see if there is a date - thanks.

Comment: My recommendation: use the credit to purchase something from Lowes online. These days I'm pretty sure all Lowes stores are even offering curbside pickup so as long as what you're looking for is in stock, you don't have to wait for the product to be delivered to your house.

Answer (score 10):

This seems like it should be an easy fix. If the license doesn't match due to a typing error, then presumably most of the information would be correct, or close to correct, so viewing what they have side by side with your info should nearly line up. If not, then maybe the typo was in the credit ID- meaning that your information got assigned to a different store credit ID. They may be able to look it up that way, but it wouldn't surprise me if they can't search for all store credit by person.

As for what to do? Does the card containing the store credit have a phone number on it? If yes call it and see if they can fix it for you. If not, I'd try the customer support counter at the store, preferably the one that issued the card.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the answer here that this is likely something that can be fixed if you're willing to push a little bit. Still, there might be an even easier way: just purchase something from Lowes online using the credit. Most likely the online purchase form doesn't try to verify that the card matches your ID. As long as the product is in stock, you should be able to order for pickup in-store, so you wouldn't have to wait for it to be delivered to your house.
EDIT:
Unfortunately, a merchandise return card can not be used for Lowes.com or LowsforPros.com.